# Oracle SOA suite domain error

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, database-schema, oracle-fusion-middleware, soa-suite

I'm trying to create SOA Suite 11g domain via Fusion Middleware Configuration wizard and I'm stuck at the step where I need to configure JDBC component schema. The walkthrough I'm reading specifically says that one should not modify username to the schemas because it will be automatically assigned. But, whenever I try to proceed, I get an error/warning that says that that's what I have to do. If I do it manually, the test fails... Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the schema username you created when you ran the Repository Creation Utility (RCU), then this name *must* be  used in the domain creation screen.
For ex: I am installing FMW 11.7 and 11.8. I will create two different schemas using RCU: DEV7 and DEV8. When I run the Config Wizard for the .7 domain portion, I will specify DEV7 as the username for the JDBC connections - having to set the user name separate for each schema. Then I do the same for the .8 portions, but specify DEV8 for the username of those JDBC connections.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the test in the next step still isn't successful. The username I chose was sys, if I remember correctly, and I set that username for all component schemas as schema owner. The error that is displayed is

"Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor"

I am also confused because in the tutorial, the owner names look like some registry values or system variables: DEV_ORABAM for BAM shema, DEV_SOAINFRA for SOA Infrastructure and so on...

Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt it's SYS. But you can check by looking at your <oracledbhome>/oradata/<db>  in there should be the schemas you created it's probably DEVxxx something. if not, then you may need to rerun the RCU and this time write down the name of the user account! And of course, you have to be able to connect via JDBC tho the db - the error you mention is common and well handled on the web.